# Image+OCR recognition in Python

Tags: python, image-recognition

I need a Python3 package recommendation for some basic image recognition. I need a package to integrate it with another Python program, not a GUI program that cannot be automatized.

I have a batch of jpg files with some icons on them, but they are expected, in the sense that they can only be from a set of 20+ icons. I have several, and can obtain more, if necessary 1000+ and up. All have the same size.

Below said icons there are alpha-numeric codes. The position of all elements is also predictable, not random.

For example, in the upper left corner you see a yellow circular dot with something like XYZ-232554 below it.

Answer (score 5):

When I hear image recognition, I immediately think [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) (where CV stands for Computer Vision).

It has excellent support for Python, with lots of [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html).

For OCR, you want [Tessract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/).

And a quick search will find some useful tutorials, such as :

- [A comprehensive guide to OCR with Tesseract, OpenCV and Python](https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/)
- [OpenCV OCR and text recognition with Tesseract](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/)
- [Deep Learning based Text Recognition (OCR) using Tesseract and OpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-text-recognition-ocr-using-tesseract-and-opencv/)

I will leave it to you to search for more tutorials, but that's your answer. Good luck

Comment: I'll give this combination a try. At another place, I was recommended the combination TensorFlow+Keras, which seems less specific.

Comment: Did you ever get answer? Fell free to post your own (or accept this), in order to help others who read this question in future.